Sphinx stops printing out messages
Sphinx (make html) stops printing out messages after processing .rst file with .. automodule::
shows messages up to 'reading sources'
reading sources... [ 43%] service_code
Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.

and then the final message.
I am expecting all messages being shown.
here fragment of the output:

reading sources... [ 43%] service_code
[app] emitting event: 'env-purge-doc'(<sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment object at 0x7a71119e6050>, 'service_code')
[app] emitting event: 'source-read'('service_code', ['Services Code\n=============\n\n\n    \n   \nGet Test\n~~~~~~~~\ntest of auto import\n\n.. automodule:: ibis.views.login\n    :members:\n '])
[autodoc] /home/jacek/workspace/ibis3_i2i/branches/3.9/ibis/static/sphinx/service_code.rst:11: input:
.. automodule:: ibis.views.login
:members:

[autodoc] import ibis.views.login
Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.

Maybe the --verbose option on sphinx-build is what you are looking for: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-v

I’ve tried using the --verbose flag and also tested with a lower version of Sphinx. The issue occurs intermittently — sometimes it works, and other times it doesn’t. I’m currently using Sphinx 8.1.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. The pages are still being built, so there’s no loss of functionality, but it’s quite annoying.
